# Use jQuery to Convert DateTime URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a web page that is passing the current date and time in UTC as a parameter to my web page:

```
Example: https://test.com/SentValues.html?dtype=9/23/2015+2:15:16+PM&ltype=http://abc.xyz/test.html
```

How can I convert it to a date time value in jQuery? I can't seem to get this to work. Currently, DateSent variable is storing 9/23/2015+2015+2:15:16+PM. I can't seem to convert it to  a date time.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var DateSent = decodeURIComponent(GetURLParameter('dtype'));
    var WebSite = GetURLParameter('ltype');
    var PassedDT = new Date(DateSent);
    var MinCurrentDT = new Date($.now());
    var MaxCurrentDT = new Date($.now());

    MinCurrentDT.setMinutes(MinCurrentDT.getMinutes() - 5);
    MaxCurrentDT.setMinutes(MaxCurrentDT.getMinutes() + 5);

    if (PassedDT >= MinCurrentDT && PassedDT <= MaxCurrentDT) {
         alert('Inside range.');
    }
    else {
        alert('Outside range.');
    }       

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"+" is not encoded in a way that decodeURIComponent can handle.  It would expect spaces to be represented as `%20`.  By replacing the "+" with a space manually, it makes a valid date object.

```js
///////// Encoded with +

var url = "https://test.com/SentValues.html?dtype=9/23/2015+2:15:16+PM&ltype=http://abc.xyz/test.html";

// Extract dtype from URL
var dtype = url.split("dtype=");
dtype = dtype.length > 0 ? dtype[1] : "";
dtype = decodeURIComponent(dtype.split("&")[0]);
dtype = dtype.replace(/\+/g, " "); // Replace "+" with spaces

document.getElementById("plusresult").innerHTML = new Date(dtype);

///////// Encoded with %20

url = "https://test.com/SentValues.html?dtype=9/23/2015%202:15:16%20PM&ltype=http://abc.xyz/test.html";

// Extract dtype from URL
dtype = url.split("dtype=");
dtype = dtype.length > 0 ? dtype[1] : "";
dtype = decodeURIComponent(dtype.split("&")[0]);
// No replacement necessary

document.getElementById("encoderesult").innerHTML = new Date(dtype);
```

```html
<p>Result for URL with "+": <span id="plusresult"></span></p>
<p>Result for URL with "%20": <span id="encoderesult"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I didn't notice that the space was replaced by a + instead of %20. Maybe it's not actually a regular space?? In the .NET code that is generating the DateTime value, the HttpUtility.UrlEncode inserting a plus sign instead of %20.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?
I made an example using moment in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zeevack/), but you can view other methods to use here: http://momentjs.com/docs/

```
moment(MaxCurrentDT).format('HH:mm:ss DD-MM-YYYY')
//output: 14:07:35 23-09-2015
```